# R Project - How does one change the color of console text?

Tags: r, text, console

When warnings or errors are reported in the console the text color is red.  I have a function that reads a file and does some plotting where I generate some warnings occasionally.  When the warnings are generated the console text color stays red for the rest of the session.  I've looked at the warning function but can't see where the color is set and reset.  Is there a way to reset the text color in the base installation?

Comment: Those colours are defined in the file Rconsole in the `~/etc` folder and should return back to normal after the warning is printed. Are you using RGui, RStudio, rkward, other? This seems to be a bug in the installation or maybe a `.RData` file definition.

Comment: You can use colors from `crayon` if you wish. For instance `cat(crayon::blue("Hi"))`. Use this to change your function's warnings' color(s).

Comment: I'm using the R package console that comes with the standard R instalation.  Yeah, the lack of return to the correct color (black) seemed a buggish behavior, but it was minor and I thought it was more like changing a par setting and not resetting par.  I thought a color set option would be an easy workaround, and perhaps worth a bug report after confirming it wasn't my bad.  Also, learning how text color is set in base might be worth the effort for future functions.  Since it seemed a buggy sort of thing I didn't want to add another layer of function (crayon:NelsonGon's suggestion).

Comment: BTW, what theme are you using, if at all you are using RStudio? Dark or white?

Comment: Hmmmm. Crayon doesn't change the color of text in my installation.

Comment: I don't wan tto mislead on my environment.  The "About R" command returns a small window containing information which in part shows "R 3.5.2 GUI 1.70 El Capitan build (7612)" and "Check for Updates" says I'm up to date.

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2574